# "mounded and dipped in the centre"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am translating an article about cow patties :)
Here's the passage I feel a bit confused about

> “I like to see the cow pies looking kind of like a pumpkin pie,
>   **mounded and dipped in the middle**,” said Dennis.

I have found some pumpkin pie pictures on the Internet, but they don't seem to look like this description, so I thought maybe I didn't properly understand the verbs "mounded and dipped'.

Does this expression "mounded and dipped in the middle' mean that the pie looks like a little mound (or hill) and is a bit hollow in the middle? I tried to draw it as well:)
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hahahahahaha! I think this it the very first hand-drawn cow patty we've ever been graced with on EL&U. Thanks for the laugh. And yes, that's how I interpret the description too.

Comment: Summarizing your research (e.g. definitions of the two words) will get you an answer instead of a closing. Please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: @medica Summarizing her research? She drew a literal picture!

Comment: Seriously. That's not research. [An actual cow pie image](http://integraldeeplistening.com/carrying-cow-pies/) might be better than a drawing or a description. Which is somewhat universal and transcends the English language.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I had asked the question here as I found no pumpkin pie-like cow patty-

Comment: @ElizavetaLevina - There are tons of such pictures on the internet. Having seen many cow pies in my youth, I can tell you I never mistook one for a pumpkin pie, nor was I reminded of one. Also, the author's description of how a pumpkin pie should look is presumptuous. Maybe a soufflé, but not a pumpkin pie.

Comment: +1 for *cow pies* and *cow patties*. I thought they were only called [*cowpats*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cowpats), and for teaching me about their shape, although  Dennis should have said "sunk" in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a picture of the type of pumpkin pie Dennis is talking about click [here](http://www.organicroots.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/whole-pumpkin-pie.jpg).  Pumpkin pie filling is dense, and if the pie bakes unevenly, the center may sink as the pie cools.

For a picture of the type of cow pie (also called a "cow patty") that Dennis likes to see, click [here](http://hazelfreeman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/CowPatty.jpg).

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvoter, a plague on this site.

Comment: That cowpie looks like it's been stepped on. It's not just dipped, it's dented.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock If you say so.